# Line break in cmd "for in () do ()"

Tags: windows, batch-file

There is a single line code

```
cmd /v/c "for %%i in ("%CD%\*.txt") do @(call rename "%%i" "%%~ni1.txt" & call echo 1)"
pause
```

How to inject line break to get something like this?

```
cmd /v/c "for %%i in ("%CD%\*.txt") do @(call rename "%%i" "%%~ni1.txt" & ^
call echo 1)"
pause
```

If it is impossible, just write that this is impossible.

Comment: It would help if you were to explain what you're trying to achieve. Could you please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/59356403/edit) to include the expected output and perhaps a few example filenames, to run the code against.

Comment: When you're on it, please also explain why you are using `cmd /v/c` and `call`.

Comment: Not knowing what you are trying to achieve or what is the purpose of all this, the line continuation you are trying to do (`^`) cannot work, because it appears in between `""`, so the caret `^` is not recognised as a special character; you could try to remove the outer-most pair of `""` or to escape them like `^"`...

Comment: jeb, this is not dublicate, ^ is not working, man

Comment: @qweqwe1, follow the advice in the comments and edit your question with sufficient information for us to determine that the linked question does not provide the solution to your issue. If you do not do that your question will remain closed.

Comment: Compo, all is described in the topic, no more, no less.

Comment: it's absolutely irrelevant to `for` or `do`. It's just that [`^` doesn't work as an escape character inside quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4095133/995714)

Answer (score 0):

Although I have no idea what you want to accomplish with `cmd /v /c` and the `call` commands:

```
cmd /v/c ^"for %%i in ("%CD%\*.txt") do @(call rename "%%i" "%%~ni1.txt" & ^
call echo 1
```

Note: your `^` didn't work, because it was inside a quoted string. By escaping the opening quote, you can overcome this limitation.
Be aware that the line break breaks context, so omit the closing `"` and the closing `)` in the second line (as they are both disconnected from their opening counterpart and so do nothing special any more).